# Is there any opensource program in PHP which make use of Rackspacecloud API?

Tags: php, json, api, rest, rackspace-cloud

I want to use Rackspace API which is based on ReST. 
I am able to get all the output using GET request (Using CURL in PHP).
Here is a piece of information I found which I could not understand:

```
Example 4.4. Server Create Request: 

JSON 
  {
  "server" : {
  "name" : "new-server-test",
  "imageId" : 1,
  "flavorId" : 1,
  "metadata" : {
    "My Server Name" : "Apache1"
  },
  "personality" : [
    {
      "path" : "/etc/banner.txt",
      "contents" :
      "ICAgICAgDQoiQSBjbG91ZCBkb2VzIG5vdCBrbm93IHdoeSBp
      dCBtb3ZlcyBpbiBqdXN0IHN1Y2ggYSBkaXJlY3Rpb24gYW5k
      IGF0IHN1Y2ggYSBzcGVlZC4uLkl0IGZlZWxzIGFuIGltcHVs
      c2lvbi4uLnRoaXMgaXMgdGhlIHBsYWNlIHRvIGdvIG5vdy4g
      QnV0IHRoZSBza3kga25vd3MgdGhlIHJlYXNvbnMgYW5kIHRo
      ZSBwYXR0ZXJucyBiZWhpbmQgYWxsIGNsb3VkcywgYW5kIHlv
      dSB3aWxsIGtub3csIHRvbywgd2hlbiB5b3UgbGlmdCB5b3Vy
      c2VsZiBoaWdoIGVub3VnaCB0byBzZWUgYmV5b25kIGhvcml6
      b25zLiINCg0KLVJpY2hhcmQgQmFjaA=="
      }
    ]
  }
 }
```

Now how do I make a Request In JSON format?
Is there any implementation of RackSpace Cloud Server API which I can see and understand?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I have never used it, but with a quick search on everyone's favourite search engine I found [rackspace-cloud-api](https://github.com/dshafik/rackspace-cloud-api/):

> The Rackspace Cloud API for PHP is
>   intended to be a full API for all
>   Rackspace Cloud services.
>
> The initial offering focuses on Cloud
>   Servers.
>
> To use this API, you must place a copy
>   of the Zend framework in your
>   include_path.

Looks like it is based on Zend Framework.

Another github hosted project is [Rackspace-Cloud-PHP-Library](https://github.com/pas256/Rackspace-Cloud-PHP-Library), which again I have not used. The maintainers homepage also has some detail: http://blog.pas.net.au/2009/08/rackspace-cloud-api-php-library/

> The Rackspace Cloud has released an
>   API for their Cloud Servers which you
>   can find here:
>
> http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/servers/api
>   The Cloud Server API is currently in
>   beta, and does not have any libraries
>   available to simplify making calls, so
>   I have created this PHP one.
>
> This is strictly for PHP5 since PHP4
>   should be forgotten forever.
>
> The API has some poorly written
>   documentation, but it is still useful.
>   You can find it at this address:
>   http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/servers/api/cs-devguide-latest.pdf

Comment: I was going through the "poorly written" guide http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/servers/api/cs-devguide-latest.pdf, There only I found that piece of code which I couldn't understand.